# Compiling OpenCV-contrib for IOS (especially the SFM-Module)

Tags: ios, macos, opencv

I've tried to install openCV_contrib for IOS, therefore I execute

```
python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py "framework_dest"
```

on my Mac (I need Xcode for compiling openCV for IOS) but all the times, i got the message:

```
-- Checking SFM deps... FALSE
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags
```

I need the SFM module, hence I tried installing Glog and Gflags at several ways: using

```
brew install glog gflags
```

and brew outputs, that those packages are successfully installed respective already installed.

Later I tried to compile both from GitHub on my own, but with no success, I'm still not able to compile SFM for IOS.

On Linux I could compile openCV including the SFM module, but I can't compile it for IOS, because Xcode is not available for Linux.

I don't know, what to do! Do some of you know how to install glog/gflags on Mac or do you know how to build the IOS-Framework of OpenCV on Linux or maybe how to build the IOS-Framework on my Mac using the binaries created with `cmake .. && make` in my Linux (because there SFM is compiled)?

There have to be some solution, because Mac is based on Linux, so if it works on Linux, why doesn't it work on my Mac?!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution? Even I want to build OpenCV with Contrib for iOS.

Comment: Yes! After a few days of intensive work I got the solution: I had to modify the path in the cmake-files, I don't know why, but these are completely wrong. I will post my modified version in a few days ;)

Comment: @MoritzK. Wanna share your solution?